# Fixing clogged washer drain pipe

Tags: plumbing, washing-machine, clog

My washer drain pipe backed up today and I tried fixing it with one of these with no luck so far

[image: drain cleaner]

I imagine it has to do with this tight turn in the drain pipe:

[image: drain pipe]

I thought maybe an auger would be better for this sort of thing, but the guy at Home Depot convinced me to get the snake instead.

Am I using the right tool for this? Anything that might be able to make this easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That snake is a nice one I would open that vent on the end and go straight in with the snake it should do the job, an augger only goes to the trap for the most part and in my experiance the plug is further down where other things connect. If you can't get that vent off you may be able to go to a sink that is close or find another clean out but remove the trap and go straight in. In my location that vent would require an air admittance valve since it is inside and some areas don't allow that at all (even though it is the same as a sink trap).

Comment: If you dont see another easy access, you're going to need to wire brush and clean the painted area, even soak it or use heat. Ideally use a "nice" solid plumbers box end wrench (two of them) to break that free. You could clean the elbow  once its off if that a question.

Comment: @noybman I have a huge wrench that did the trick :)